# Function doesn't update in asyncio

Tags: python, django, postgresql, python-asyncio, aiogram

I'm writing a bot in aiogram with a backend on django for postgresql (had the same issue before converting from pure psycopg2).

One of the finite states I'm in, should constantly check for updates in the DB, except it doesn't happen. Here's the code for the loop in bot:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Current.start_state)
async def func(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):
    async def res():
        return await function(args)

    global ticket
    ticket = await res()

    while ticket == -1:
        ticket = await res()
        if ticket == -1:
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            print(ticket) #debugging
```

I've tried it without the function:

```
@dp.message_handler(state=Current.start_state)
async def func(msg: types.Message, state: FSMContext):

    global ticket 
    ticket = await function(args)

    while ticket == -1:
        ticket = await function(args)
        if ticket == -1:
            await asyncio.sleep(3)
            print(ticket )
```

And many other combinations, including making the loop condition while = True and having a break in the loop for when the condition is met. And I can insure you, the results change, I can see that in pgAdmin4 and by running this function separately in another script while the bot is running. It seems to work sometimes if I manually change the information in DB, and even then, not always. Basically, whilst this loop is running for user A, another user B adds stuff to the DB, which should show up for user A. When done through the bot, user A's information doesn't get updated at all, unlike when changing the information in the DB manually.
It seems to function correctly when I use time.sleep(), but that obviously blocks the thread and no one else can use the bot.

This is the function that queries the database:

```
@sync_to_async
def function(args):

    admin = User.objects.get(username=args)
    ticket = Tickets.objects.filter(admin_nick=admin, accepted=None)[:1]

    if ticket:
        return ticket.values()[0]
    else:
            return -1
```

I had to use the sync_to_async decorator, because I'm not sure of a better way to make a django function async.

Comment: Why is `ticket` a global variable?

Comment: I'm using it in other functions later on

Comment: Just tried setting it to another variable, in case that might be the reason. Didn't change